# Mayor número de ceros seguidos en Haskell

Tags: haskell, programación-funcional

En Haskell, tengo definida las siguientes funciones:

```
import Numeric
import Data.Char
import Data.List

   toBin :: Integer -> Integer
   toBin n = read (showIntAtBase 2 intToDigit n "")

    -- λ> toBin 558745840
    -- 100001010011011100100011110000
    -- (0.01 secs, 117,680 bytes)

    digitos :: Integer -> [[Integer]]
    digitos n = group [read[d] | d <- show n]

    -- λ> digitos(toBin 558745840)
    -- [[1],[0,0,0,0],[1],[0],[1],[0,0],[1,1],[0],[1,1,1],[0,0],[1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]]
    -- (0.01 secs, 288,624 bytes)
```

Tengo que hacer una función que me diga el mayor números de cero seguidos en el número en forma binario. O sea,

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f 558745840 = 4
f 2018 = 3
f 529 = 4
```

`f 558745840` = 4 porque 1**0000**101001101110010001111**0000**, tiene 4 ceros seguidos. ¿Me pueden ayudar, por favor?

He intentado hacer lo siguiente, pero en algunos casos falla:

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f = maximum (map length digitos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes escribir directamente la función `toBin` para que devuelva una lista de `1`s y `0`s:

```
toBin :: Int -> [Int]
toBin 0 = [0]
toBin n = reverse $ bin n
    where
        bin 0 = []
        bin n = n `mod` 2 : bin (n `div` 2)
```

Ahora, para obtener el mayor número de `0`s seguidos:

- La función `toBin` convierte el número a binario como una lista de `1`s y `0`s.
- La función `group` de `Data.List` agrupa la lista de `1`s y `0`s en sublistas de `1`s y `0`s consecutivos.
- La función `filter ((==0).head)` filtra las sublistas de contengan `0`s (con comprobar el primer elemento es suficiente).
- La función `map length` devuelve la lista con las longitudes de las sublistas de `0`s.
- La función `maximum` devuelve el mayor número de la lista.

Juntándolo en una función tenemos:

```
import Data.List(group)
f :: Int -> Int
f = maximum . (0:) . map length . filter ((==0).head) . group . toBin
```

La función `(0:)` añade un `0` para evitar errores si no hay ningún 0 en el número binario. Por ejemplo:

```
f 558745840 = 4
f 2018 = 3
f 529 = 4
```